# Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r

I can run `ggplot2` in Rstudio but when I am running same in `shinydashboard`, I am getting this error:

> "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values"

The problem is I have created dynamic input from server. I defaulted the dynamic input to first value of the list. based on the input selection I will do the subset of data and will plot.

I can run same in Rshiny but facing error while using shinydashboard package

Comment: A possibility worth trying is to use as.numeric(input$yvalue) and ensure you really hand over numeric values to your plot

Answer (score 0):

check your NAs also:
[R: need finite 'ylim' values in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871292/r-need-finite-ylim-values-in-function)
and
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/299789.html