# "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values" error when creating interaction plots in R

Tags: r, for-loop, interaction

I am trying to create interaction plots for data that looks like the following:

```
goal  behavior  dv1  dv2  dv3
1     1         4    2    6
1     5         3    5    1
1     7         2    4    2
5     1         5    2    7
5     5         2    1    3
5     7         2    1    2
7     1         4    5    7
7     5         2    1    4
7     7         3    2    5
```

As you can see, there are 9 conditions (3 possibilities for goal x 3 possibilities for behavior). In the actual dataset, there are approximately 25-30 participants for each of the 9 conditions.

This is the code I have used to create interaction plots in the past. "factor_values" is a list that includes the names of each dependent variable. I am trying to create a plot for each item in the "factor_values" list. "dfc" is the dataframe.

```
for(i_factor_value in factor_values) {
  interaction.plot(dfc$goal, dfc$behavior, 
               dfc[[i_factor_value]], ylab = i_factor_value) }
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

Why am I getting this error? What should I change in order to create these plots?

The solution to my problem is not available in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871292/r-need-finite-ylim-values-in-function) or in others that I've looked at, even though the error message is the same. There are no NA's in my dataframe, and many of the solutions propose adding na.rm = TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with by adding as.numeric() to the code like so:

```
for(i_factor_value in factor_values) {
  interaction.plot(dfc$goal, dfc$behavior, 
               as.numeric(dfc[[i_factor_value]]), ylab = i_factor_value)}
```